# Regex: Find Word ignoring innertext in Anchor tag

Tags: .net, regex, regex-negation

Using .NET.

Sample String to search:

`For more information on foreclosures visit <a href="http://www.us.gov/foreclosures.aspx">forclosures</a>`

Need regex to find(and subsequently replace) the word foreclosures in this string...but only the instance(s) outside of the anchor tag.  So in this example, only the first instance of the word "foreclosures" should be matched. Anything inside of an anchor tag should be completely ignored.

The regex that I have so far (which does NOT correctly exclude the inner text yet) is:

`\bforeclosures(?!([^<]+)?>)`

UPDATED: After 1st response provided already...
I'm using VB.NET, but am fluent in C# as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is better to do things in more steps than one. Rather than spending hours coming up with the perfect Regular Expression to rule them all, you could start by removing all html tags with a pretty simple call to `Regex.Replace`:

```
// Remove html tags
var htmlTagPattern = new Regex(@"<([A-Z][A-Z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var noTags = htmlTagPattern.Replace(input, string.Empty);

// Find those words
var foreclosuresPattern = new Regex(@"foreclosures", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var matches = foreclosuresPattern.Matches(noTags);
```

EDIT: The original post only mentioned **finding** words. The need to **replace** words adds a bit more complexity.

```
// Try and find all cases
private string findAndTag(string input) {
    var pattern = new Regex(@"(\x3c[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*[^\x3e]*)?(foreclosures)([^\x3c\x3e]*>)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return pattern.Replace(matches, replacer);
}

private string replacer(Match match) {
    if (match.Groups[1].Success) {
        // Found the word foreclosures inside a tag, for
        // example <a href="foreclosures">...
        // Just return the original match - don't replace
        return match.Value;
    }
    else {
        // Found the word outside of tags
        // Tag it and return it
        return "<span>" + match.Value + "</span>";
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that I have to find and replace the word foreclosure with a tagged version of the same word, but only outside of an anchor tag.

Comment: Syntatically the regex that you provided is giving me some issues in RegExBuddy... at the )? part, can you confirm the regex?

Comment: It works fine in regexr: http://regexr.com?2vp50 - and it works fine in my test ConsoleApp.